# Worksheet_Change(ByVal faixa As Range) stop macro in case the range in empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have run the code below in my worksheet and I need to stop running it in case the row is empty. Please note that I need to stop showing the date or let me to delete it in column A (1) when the line is blank. The thing is that when I delete the data in lines I cannot delete the date in the column A - the macro is running and cannot let me do it.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal faixa As Range)
Dim dados As Range
Set dados = Range("A1:AI400")
If Not Intersect(faixa, dados) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
dados.Cells(faixa.Row, 1).Value = Date
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like you don't need `dados` to include Column A: try `B1:AI400` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your code is running even when you intend to leave a blank cell if I understand correctly. To correct it, the following would allow you to leave a blank cell:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal faixa As Range)

Dim dados As Range
Set dados = Range("A1:AI4000")

If Not Intersect(faixa, dados) Is Nothing Then
     If Not faixa = "" Then
        dados.Cells(faixa.Row, 1).value = Date
     End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi JGrSmi, It has worked well. thank you! Now I can delete the first column date in case the cell is blank. I am facing another problem here: I believe it would be better to have the first column date updated only if the range from B2:AI400 is updated, however when I change the range to B2:AI400 in the formula, the column A stops to be updated with today's date. Do you know how to solve this pls? Is that happening since the column with the date stamp needs to be within the range pls?